# System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null. Arg_ParamName_Name'

Tags: c#, api, dictionary, post

I have an error in the api I'm building for learning purposes, I'm not quite sure how I would go about solving this error '*System.ArgumentNullException: 'Value cannot be null.

The request I'm trying to make is a post request here is a screenshot of postman;
[image: screenshot of postman POST HTTP request].

The http request; `https://localhost:44360/vendor` which is a POST method

Arg_ParamName_Name*'. I using dictionary to build a small crud api for me use in reactjs. I haven't used dictionary before in c#.
[image: screenshot of the error and main service]

I am trying to add a new coffee using this line of code as follows:

```
public void create(Drink drink)
    {
        VENDORS.Add(drink.Vendor, drink.Ingredients);
    }
```

Here is the model;

```
namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class Drink
    {
        public List<string> Ingredients { get; set; }

        public string Vendor { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is what the controller looks like

[image: Screenshot of the main controller]

But there seems to be something that I may have missed but I have no idea. Does anyone have any idea what I can do to fix this issue? Any help will be highly appreciate.

Comment: Without showing us your HTTP request, we cannot help.

Comment: Sorry about that I've just added a screenshot of the http request now.

Comment: We can't copy-paste from screenshots - please **edit the actual request body into your question**. That also goes for the controller and repository/service.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request is incorrect. `[]` in JSON indicates an array, but you aren't passing an array of drinks; your ingredients are the array. Probably what you want is something like the following:

```
drink: {
    vendor: "Bob",
    ingredients: [
        "Milk",
        "Lemon Coffee"
    ]
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I’ve tried your solution but I am still getting the same error.